# What is the difference between code coverage and line coverage in sonar

Tags: code-coverage, sonarqube

I know what the difference is between line and branch coverage, but what is the difference between code coverage and line coverage? Is the former instruction coverage?

Comment: coverage seems to be a computed metric, that takes line and branch coverage into consideration. Can't find the formula though :D

Comment: hence the question. I think it is instruction coverage as one line of java code can have multiple instructions these two are different. Maybe there will an authoritative answer here ;)

Comment: fabrice from sonar roams this tag, so I think will get some info :)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Coverage is a subtle ;-) mix of the line and the branch coverage.

You can find the formula on our [metric description page](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/user-guide/metric-definitions/):

```
coverage = (CT + CF + LC)/(2*B + EL)
 
where
 
CT - branches that evaluated to "true" at least once
CF - branches that evaluated to "false" at least once
LC - lines covered (lines_to_cover - uncovered_lines)
 
B - total number of branches (2*B = conditions_to_cover)
EL - total number of executable lines (lines_to_cover)
```

Comment: awesome, I was unable to find that page via google... THanks!

Answer (score 4):

To expand on the answer, you can only query sonar for these terms:

1. conditions_to_cover
2. uncovered_conditions
3. lines_to_cover
4. uncovered_lines

And then you can covert to the terms above using these equations:

```
CT + CF = conditions_to_cover - uncovered_conditions
2*B = conditions_to_cover
LC = lines_to_cover - uncovered_lines
EL = lines_to_cover
```

You can use the Sonar Drilldown or REST API to get the metric values above:

```
http://my.sonar.com/drilldown/measures/My-Project-Name?metric=line_coverage 

http://my.sonar.com/api/resources?resource=55555&metrics=ncloc,conditions_to_cover,uncovered_conditions,lines_to_cover,uncovered_lines,coverage,line_coverage,branch_coverage,it_conditions_to_cover,it_uncovered_conditions,it_lines_to_cover,it_uncovered_lines,it_coverage,it_line_coverage,it_branch_coverage,overall_conditions_to_cover,overall_uncovered_conditions,overall_lines_to_cover,overall_uncovered_lines,overall_coverage,overall_line_coverage,overall_branch_coverage
```

This blog post has additional information: http://sizustech.blogspot.com/2015/10/making-sense-of-sonar-qube-stats-like.html

Comment: It was very unclear that CT + CF in fact conditions_to_cover - uncovered_conditions and 2*B = conditions_to_cover, thanks for highlighting!