# SonarQube for .Net project, code coverage not excluding file marked with "ExcludeFromCodeCoverage"

Tags: c#, .net, sonarqube, dotcover

I have a .Net project and I have recently integrated Sonar to measure the code coverage but the Coverage is very low compared to coverage that I see in DotCover. When I checked in details, found that SonarQube is still counting the C# classes marked with "ExcludeFromCodeCoverage" attributes for Code Coverage. Is there any setting that I need to update in SonarQube build?

Comment: May this can help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35876546/code-coverage-differences-in-sonarqube-net

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for investigating this issue. I can confirm that we do not take `ExcludeFromCodeCoverage` into account. Created a JIRA ticket for this: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARCS-611

Comment: Sorry, I can't commit to any timeframe now. I think you should expect it in 2-3 months.

Comment: This is currently set to `Resolution: Won't Fix`. What is the alternative if his is not going to be fixed?

Comment: @CarlThomas Issues have been moved to GitHub. The team will respond, please follow up in comments there: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-csharp/issues/428 or in related tickets.